# Hotspot Analysis QGIS Error: An error has occurred while executing Python code: ValueError: Illegal field requested in GetField()

Tags: qgis, python, numpy, pysal

I am doing a hotspot analysis for chicken spatial distribution in QGIS using Ubuntu. I have already installed the repositories used for hotspot analysis. However, an error occurred after I chose a layer and its attribute table. It says:

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

> ValueError: Illegal field requested in GetField()  Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/home/envisci/.qgis2/python/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/hotspot_analysis.py",
>   line 565, in run
>       u.append(geometry.GetField(C))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 4707, in
>   GetField
>       raise ValueError("Illegal field requested in GetField()") ValueError: Illegal field requested in GetField()

Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 
QGIS version: 2.14.5-Essen Essen, exported

Python Path:

> /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing /usr/share/qgis/python
>   /home/envisci/.qgis2/python /home/envisci/.qgis2/python/plugins
>   /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins /usr/lib/python2.7
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /home/envisci/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0 /home/envisci/.qgis2//python
>   /home/envisci/.qgis2/python/plugins/gearthview/ext-libs
>   /home/envisci/.qgis2/python/plugins/DigitizingTools/tools
>   /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools
>   /media/envisci/msguimalan/RA

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Include your code to show what you were trying so people will be able to help you

Comment: Hi, all i did is install the hotspot plugin from https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin, then select a layer from the layer panel... i did not put any code aside from the installation..

Comment: Well, you could upgrade to QGIS-3 and use the new version of the package: https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin/tree/qgis3

Comment: Sounds like a geometry error. Are there any?